# PHP array VS MSQL table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, performance

I have a program that creates logs and these logs are used to calculate balances, trends, etc for each individual client. Currently, I store everything in separate MYSQL tables. I link all the logs to a specific client by joining the two tables. When I access a client, it pulls all the logs from the log_table and generates a report. The report varies depending on what filters are in place, mostly date and category specific.

My concern is the performance of my program as we accumulate more logs and clients. My intuition tells me to store the log information in the user_table in the form of a serialized array so only one query is used for the entire session. I can then take that log array and filter it using PHP where as before, it was filtered in a MYSQL query (using multiple methods, such as BETWEEN for dates and other comparisons).

My question is, do you think performance would be improved if I used serialized arrays to store the logs as opposed to using a MYSQL table to store each individual log? We are estimating about 500-1000 logs per client, with around 50000 clients (and growing).

Comment: You realise that you can retrieve more than one row of a database table with a single SQL query.... the problem is that you're using multiple tables, when you should be using a single table

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I am using two tables in this case, client_table and log_table. The client_table has an ID which is used to link each individual log to the appropriate client. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think I misunderstood.... I thought you were using a separate log table for every client

Comment: However, performance will degrade rapidly if you take the approach off serializing your data, and do all your filtering in PHP..... filtering in SQL queries is using the right tool for the job, as long as your table is sensibly indexed

Comment: What indexes do you have on the two tables? What query are you using to retrieve the log data now? And what does an EXPLAIN show for that query?

Comment: Ok, so more rows is better than one row with a column of large data? I have researched this, have yet to find a reason for

Comment: The reason is that relational databases are designed and optimized to work with data with indexes and relationships.... each log entry should be one row, so you can retrieve only those that you actually need in the SQL query. PHP is not optimised for filtering data in the same way as the database, making it a lot slower than a properly indexed database table; and it has a memory limitation that means it will have major problems as your volume of data grows if you need to retrieve that large volume into PHP's restricted memory space in order to do your filtering there.

Comment: The log query is dynamic, but looks like this: select * FROM log_table WHERE (client_id = '$client_id’) AND (date BETWEEN $date[start] AND $date[end]) 

Other filters could be added as well, such as (category_id = ‘$category_id’), etc. 

I have not run an EXPLAIN yet, I am working on one now.

Comment: What indexes do you have on your tables? At the very least, you need an index on `client_id`, but probably a compound index on `client_id` and `date`. Edit the details into your answer

Comment: Indexes are Primary Key, set on the ID column. I think you are right, I am going to update my tables so they are indexed with those columns.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't understand what makes databases powerful. It's not about "storing data", it's about "storing data in a way that can be indexed, optimized, and filtered". You don't store serialized arrays, because the database can't do anything with that. All it sees is a single string without any structure that it can meaningfully work with. Using it that way voids the entire reason to even use a database.

Instead, figure out the schema for your array data, and then insert your data properly, with one field per dedicated table column so that you can actually use the database **as a database**, allowing it to optimize its storage, retrieval, and database algebra (selecting, joining and filtering).

- Is serialized arrays in a db faster than native PHP? No, of course not. You've forced the database to act as a flat file with the extra dbms overhead.
- Is using the database properly faster than native PHP? Usually, yes, by a lot.

Plus, and this part is important, it means that your database can live "anywhere", including on a faster machine next to your webserver, so that your database can return results in 0.1s, rather than PHP jacking 100% cpu to filter your data and preventing users of your website from getting page results because you blocked all the threads. In fact, for that very reason it makes absolutely no sense to keep this task in PHP, even if you're bad at implementing your schema and queries, forget to cache results and do subsequent searches inside of those cached results, forget to index the tables on columns for extremely fast retrieval, etc, etc.

PHP is not for doing all the heavy lifting. It should ask other things for the data it needs, and act as the glue between "a request comes in", "response base data is obtained" and "response is sent back to the client". It should start up, make the calls, generate the result, and die as fast as it can again.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you need to use the data. You might want to look into storing with mongo if you don't need to search that data. If you do, leave it in individual rows and create your indexes in a way that makes them look up fast.

If you have 10 billion rows, and need to look up 100 of them to do a calculation, it should still be fast if you have your indexes done right.

Now if you have 10 billion rows and you want to do a sum on 10,000 of them, it would probably be more efficient to save that total somewhere. Whenever a new row is added, removed or updated that would affect that total, you can change that total as well. Consider a bank, where all items in the ledger are stored in a table, but the balance is stored on the user account and is not calculated based on all the transactions every time the user wants to check his balance.